# C# Winform: How to show context menu just below the datagrid button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have grid and one column type is button column. i want that when user click on button then menu should show just below the button but i am not able to achieve this. **dgList** is name of datagridview. if there is no space to show the menu then menu position will be adjusted dynamically.

### here is my code what i tried

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Salary", typeof(int));

    DataRow dr = null;
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = 1;
    dr[1] = "Joydip";
    dr[2] = 5200;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = 2;
    dr[1] = "Salim";
    dr[2] = 3200;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = 3;
    dr[1] = "Sukumar";
    dr[2] = 6000;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dgList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgList.DataSource = dt;
    dgList.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "ID";
    dgList.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Name";
    dgList.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Salary";

}

private void dgList_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int currentMouseOverRow = dgList.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
    if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0)
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(dgList, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        
}
```

I tried also this code but no luck.

```
private void dgList_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell currentCell = (sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell;
    if (currentCell != null)
    {
        ContextMenuStrip cms = currentCell.ContextMenuStrip;
        Rectangle r = currentCell.DataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(currentCell.ColumnIndex, currentCell.RowIndex, false);
        Point p = new Point(r.X + r.Width, r.Y + r.Height);
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(currentCell.DataGridView, p);
    }
}
```

please guide me what mistake is there in my code. how to achieve what i am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: See if the [following](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/DataGridViewButtonAsync) might be what you are looking for. Scroll to bottom of readme for a screenshot. If this is I can go into details of how this was written.

Comment: @KarenPayne this is the screen shot taken from your url https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/DataGridViewButtonAsync/raw/master/assets/ButtonContextMenu.png    where menu's left position and button left position is not same. how to show menu under button control where menu's left and button left will be same? please share some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed. here the working code

```
private void dgList_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell currentCell = (sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell;
    if (currentCell != null && currentCell.ColumnIndex==3)
    {
        ContextMenuStrip cms = currentCell.ContextMenuStrip;
        Rectangle r = currentCell.DataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(currentCell.ColumnIndex, currentCell.RowIndex, false);
        Point p = new Point(r.X, r.Y + r.Height);
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(currentCell.DataGridView, p);
    }
}
```